# Facebook addons for images

Tags: add-on, facebook

Are there any EE Facebook addons that can create albums from multiple images in entry when sharing entry on Facebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with standard OpenGraph meta tags. Just create a meta tag for each image in your entry and Facebook will handle the rest. I'm not sure it will create an "album" but it should attach all images to the shared post.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/full/path/to/your/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/full/path/to/your/image2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/full/path/to/your/image3.jpg" />
```

See the documentation here http://ogp.me/#array